# Vitest in Phoenix app raises: `Error: [vite-node] Failed to load phoenix`

Tags: elixir, tdd, phoenix-framework, esbuild, vitest

I want to test the JavaScript code (/assets/js) of my Phoenix app with Vitest. I have been running into an error that I have not been able to resolve:

```
assets % npm test

> assets@1.0.0 test
> vitest run


 RUN  v0.24.3 PATH

 ❯ js/file.test.js (0)

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯Failed Suites 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

 FAIL  js/file.test.js [ js/file.test.js ]
 ❯ async /APP_PATH/assets/js/channel.js:1:256
 ❯ async /APP_PATH/assets/js/helpers.js:3:31
Error: [vite-node] Failed to load phoenix
 ❯ async /APP_PATH/assets/js/file.test.js:3:31
```

Here is some of my config and deps info.

**Vitest config**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom'
  },
})
```

**ESBuild config**

```
config :esbuild,
  version: "0.14.0",
  default: [
    args:
      ~w(js/app.js --bundle --target=es2017 --outdir=../priv/static/assets --external:/fonts/* --external:/images/* --external:/icons/*),
    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__),
    env: %{"NODE_PATH" => Path.expand("../deps", __DIR__)}
  ]
```

**Phoenix deps**

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 3.0"},
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.6.6"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.4"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.6"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 3.0"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.17.5"},
      {:floki, ">= 0.30.0", only: :test},
      {:phoenix_live_dashboard, "~> 0.6"},
      {:esbuild, "~> 0.3", runtime: Mix.env() == :dev},
      {:swoosh, "~> 1.3"},
      {:telemetry_metrics, "~> 0.6"},
      {:telemetry_poller, "~> 1.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.18"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.2"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.5"}
    ]
  end
```

**Node deps**

```
{
  "name": "assets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "vitest run"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "happy-dom": "^7.6.6",
    "vitest": "^0.24.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "idb-keyval": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

Strangely enough, before I got the error, I managed to use Vitest without any problems. Seemingly out of nowhere, this error appeared.

I tried undoing my most recent code changes, to see if that would resolve the issue. I tried changing some configuration in `vitest/config`. I tried reducing the code of my tests to a minimum, to eliminate any errors in the tests themselves. Nothing has worked so far.

**Edit:**
I have been able to narrow down the problem somewhat by commenting out an import statement in my test file:

```
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from "vitest"
// import { stringToNodeArray } from "./helpers"

describe("temp", () => {
  it("makes sense", () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

The error disappears with this import statement commented out. Needless to say, I need to be able to import from other modules.

Comment: I think your `package.json` file needs Phoenix in its dependencies: `"phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix"`

Comment: That did make some difference, indeed. Now it still doesn't run the tests, though, raising: `Function.request ../deps/phoenix/assets/js/phoenix/utils.js:345:17
TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor`

Comment: A new RC of Phoenix is out. I'll try a fresh install (since I was planning to do that anyway because of the new release). Who knows, maybe the errors disappear.

Comment: I have had no more problems with Vitest and Phoenix after starting a fresh project.